# SAS assign value to each range of numbers

Tags: sql, sas

I have calculated the number of shark attacks by area, and I am wondering how I would assign a number of lifeguards to each area depending on the amount of shark attacks. I have used

```
PROC SQL; 
SELECT Area, COUNT(*) AS N FROM work.FINAL GROUP BY AREA;
```

I would like to assign lifeguards the following way:

```
5 attacks = 1 lifeguard
10 attacks = 2 lifeguards
15 attacks = 3 lifeguards
20+ attacks = 4 lifeguards
```

How would I go about doing this, and is there any way to graph this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: @20+ I think you would assign 0 lifeguards because beach is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
PROC SQL; 
SELECT Area, COUNT(*) AS attacks  
, case 
    when calculated attacks lt 5 then 0
    when calculated attacks lt 10 then 1
    when calculated attacks lt 15 then 2
    when calculated attacks lt 20 then 3
    else 4
  end as lifeguards
FROM work.FINAL GROUP BY AREA;
```